# nssplitview dividerColor return is ignored

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, nssplitview

The `dividerColor` method return color value seems to be ignored in a subclass of `NSSplitView`. I have seen various discussions about this, But I have never seen a solution.

Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "Thin divider" (`NSSplitViewDividerStyleThin`) in IB. I then tried returning `+[NSColor redColor]` and then `+[NSColor blueColor]` in my `NSSplitView` subclass, and they both work great.

What also works: If you specify "Thick divider" (`NSSplitViewDividerStyleThick`) or "Pane splitter" (`NSSplitViewDividerStylePaneSplitter`), and you're using your subclass in a *textured* window. But if the window is not textured and you use either of these two styles, then NSClearColor is used instead, and that's what you've been seeing so far.

Comment: Thank you for answer, and I have tried to repeat your suggestions in a test. However, the color of the divider remains NSClearColor. I have created the NSSplitView in IB and subclassed the NSSplitView class. In this class I have just added 
- (NSColor *) dividerColor {
    return [NSColor blackColor];
}
`, which gets successfully called. However no difference what DividerType I select or window texture the divider remains clear.

Comment: @jread1297 This is a long shot, but: Did you specify the class of the split view in IB? Did you make it the name of your own?

Comment: You are right. I overlooked that when xcode inserts a new subclass of NSSplitView into the project it includes an empty - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect`, which had to be removed.